# How to pass dynamic data from form into Firestore using Cordova?

Tags: firebase, cordova, google-cloud-firestore, cordova-2.0.0

[image: Example taken from Firebase Guide]

I have a form and I want to pass the form input values into here. How do I populate "San Francisco" dynamically based on what the form input values are?

I have tried creating variables and populate the fields with the variables as such but I received an error message that says

> error.ts:166 Uncaught FirebaseError: Function DocumentReference.set() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined (found in field eventName in document events/RNiEJ9nUxVO1IGFr0TL5)

[image]

Reference link: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#web

Comment: just to have this fully clear, you want to post the data loaded on the form to Firestore or do you want the form to be loaded with firestore data?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert form data to JavaScript object with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/convert-form-data-to-javascript-object-with-jquery)

Comment: @JoséSoní I want to upload the data loaded on the form to Firestore

Comment: I edited the answer to leave the code as a code snippet, in Stack Overflow it is better to share code as a snippet than as an image

Comment: Thank you, @JoséSoní

Answer (score 1):

The variable value was undefined. This should solve it.

```
db.collection("events").add({
    eventName: document.getElementById('eName').value.toString(),
    organiserName: document.getElementById('oName').value.toString(),
    eventDescription: document.getElementById('oDesc').value.toString(),
    eDateTime: document.getElementById('eDateTime').value.toString(),
    eType: document.getElementById('eType').value.toString(),
})
```